# Timer clock is not ticking after minimizing the application - Windows 8 Metro App

Tags: winforms, timer, windows-8, windows

Visual Studio 2012 - Windows 8 Metro App. I have implemented Timer to display current time in my app. it is working as expected below code

```
ThreadPoolTimer.CreatePeriodicTimer(async (timer) =>
            {
                this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Low,
                () =>
                {
                    this.tbDigitalClock.Text = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm") + " UTC";
                });
            }, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
```

After minimizing and waiting for 5 mins & maximize the app window. I was able to notice that the time in the app is less than 5 mins when compared to the current time.

Not sure why am I seeing this time difference. Could it be that the background thread is unable to bind the UI elements when the UI is inactive?

Note : This is working fine in windows 10 but not working in windows 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making CoreDispatcherPriority from Low to Normal made it work in Windows 8 as well.

**CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal**